# Angular, UI-Router: How do I get access to both a Ctrl and stateParam values within a template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Based on these set-ups ([Angular UI-Router testing scope inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860277/angular-ui-router-testing-scope-inheritance), [Angular ui-router - how to access parameters in nested, named view, passed from the parent template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097820/angular-ui-router-how-to-access-parameters-in-nested-named-view-passed-from)), I did the following (the third holds the relevant issue):

```
  .state("patients", {
    url: "/dashboard/patients",
    templateUrl: 'patients/index.html',
    controller: "patientCtrl"
  })
  .state("sharedPatients", {
    url: "/dashboard/patients/shared",
    templateUrl: 'patients/shared_patients.html',
    controller: "patientCtrl"
  })
  .state('showPatient', {
    url: "/dashboard/patients/:id",
    templateUrl: 'patients/show.html',
    controller: ("patientCtrl", ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.patient_id = $stateParams.id;
    }])
  })
```

Patients and sharedPatients work without a problem. I can also go to showPatient and access the variable patient_id. However, I cannot access any of the functions or variables established in patientCtrl. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The controller scope inheritance has nothing to do with the state inheritance.

Your controllers only inherit from each other if their views are nested in the DOM.

---

Also, the syntax you're using there is misleading. `controller: ("patientCtrl", [...])` will just ignore that first part. It'll only use the controller inside the array.

Comment: Still unclear. Here's my thinking: Each state is associated with a controller. I have the showPatient state and, like the states before it, I want it associated with the controller patientCtrl. I didn't expect it to automatically inherit that ctrl; I set it explicitly. However, I also need to have access to the :id parameter of its url, which I understood could be done using stateParams like above. However, this is not working within my template; I only get access to the patient_id.

Comment: Just saw your update: yes, that's exactly the point I'm confused about. How do I get access to both a Ctrl and stateParam values within a template?

Comment: Okay; after researching the controller inheritance (which is not what I was trying to do, but I'd misunderstood the examples I'd seen), I see why this doesn't work. Still working on getting something functional, however. Half way there; thanks, Joseph.